# Pandas: create a dictionary with a list of columns as values

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary

Given this `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
first=[0,1,2,3,4]
second=[10.2,5.7,7.4,17.1,86.11]
third=['a','b','c','d','e']
fourth=['z','zz','zzz','zzzz','zzzzz']
df=pd.DataFrame({'first':first,'second':second,'third':third,'fourth':fourth})
df=df[['first','second','third','fourth']]

   first  second third fourth
0      0   10.20     a      z
1      1    5.70     b     zz
2      2    7.40     c    zzz
3      3   17.10     d   zzzz
4      4   86.11     e  zzzzz
```

I can create a dictionary out of `df` using

```
a=df.set_index('first')['second'].to_dict()
```

so that I can decide what is `keys` and what is `values`. But what if you want `values` to be a list of columns, such as `second` AND `third`?

If I try this

```
b=df.set_index('first')[['second','third']].to_dict()
```

I get a weird dictionary of dictionaries

```
{'second': {0: 10.199999999999999,
  1: 5.7000000000000002,
  2: 7.4000000000000004,
  3: 17.100000000000001,
  4: 86.109999999999999},
 'third': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'}}
```

Instead, I want a dictionary of lists

```
{0: [10.199999999999999,a],
 1: [5.7000000000000002,b],
 2: [7.4000000000000004,c],
 3: [17.100000000000001,d],
 4: [86.109999999999999,e]}
```

**How to deal with this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone else can probably chime in with a pure-pandas solution, but in a pinch I think this ought to work for you. You'd basically create the dictionary on-the-fly, indexing values in each row instead.

```
d = {df.loc[idx, 'first']: [df.loc[idx, 'second'], df.loc[idx, 'third']] for idx in range(df.shape[0])}

d
Out[5]: 
{0: [10.199999999999999, 'a'],
 1: [5.7000000000000002, 'b'],
 2: [7.4000000000000004, 'c'],
 3: [17.100000000000001, 'd'],
 4: [86.109999999999999, 'e']}
```

Edit: You could also do this:

```
df['new'] = list(zip(df['second'], df['third']))

df
Out[25]: 
   first  second third fourth         new
0      0   10.20     a      z   (10.2, a)
1      1    5.70     b     zz    (5.7, b)
2      2    7.40     c    zzz    (7.4, c)
3      3   17.10     d   zzzz   (17.1, d)
4      4   86.11     e  zzzzz  (86.11, e)

df = df[['first', 'new']]

df
Out[27]: 
   first         new
0      0   (10.2, a)
1      1    (5.7, b)
2      2    (7.4, c)
3      3   (17.1, d)
4      4  (86.11, e)

df.set_index('first').to_dict()
Out[28]: 
{'new': {0: (10.199999999999999, 'a'),
  1: (5.7000000000000002, 'b'),
  2: (7.4000000000000004, 'c'),
  3: (17.100000000000001, 'd'),
  4: (86.109999999999999, 'e')}}
```

In this approach, you would first create the list (or tuple), you want to keep and then "drop" the other columns. This is basically your original approach, modified.

And if you really wanted lists instead of tuples, just `map` the `list` type onto that `'new'` column:

```
df['new'] = list(map(list, zip(df['second'], df['third'])))
```

Comment: My real `first` is a column of numbers coded as `strings` (alphanumeric values, in all honesty). So when ported into the dictionary, they appear like `u'112233'`. How to get rid of that `u` (unicode)?

Comment: That 'u' doesn't really affect the "integrity" of those strings, but if you want it gone, I would try `map(str, df['first'])`. Or even `df['first'] = [str(x) for x in df['first']]`

Comment: This should probably go as a separate question, but what if you want the tuple `(first,second)` as key of the dictionary?

Comment: Similar to how I did things above. Create a `'key'` column in `df` whose values consist of `(first, second)` tuple pairs. `df = df[['key', 'third']]; df.set_index('key').to_dict()` should get you what you want. Just try a few different things with your example dataset before trying it on your larger dataset. You're capable of doing *that much* :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html), `zip` by column `first` and convert to `dict`:

```
a = dict(zip(df['first'], df[['second','third']].values.tolist()))
print (a)
{0: [10.2, 'a'], 1: [5.7, 'b'], 2: [7.4, 'c'], 3: [17.1, 'd'], 4: [86.11, 'e']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `zip` the values:

```
In [118]:
b=df.set_index('first')[['second','third']].values.tolist()
dict(zip(df['first'].index,b))

Out[118]:
{0: [10.2, 'a'], 1: [5.7, 'b'], 2: [7.4, 'c'], 3: [17.1, 'd'], 4: [86.11, 'e']}
```